# Find words in a simple list by typing first letter (like in a standard select-box)

Tags: select, custom-controls, html-lists, autosuggest

I'm trying to make new select-boxes with a custom styling instead of the boring standard one using jquery. What it does is that is rewrites the " + " into lists.

Quick example:

```
<select class="changeSelect">
 <option value="0" selected="selected">Choose now</option>
 <option value="1">aaaaaaaaa</option>
 <option value="2">bbbbbbbbb</option>
 <option value="3">ccccccccc</option>
</select>
```

Becomes into:

```
<ul>
 <li class="first">Choose now</li>
 <li>aaaaaaaaa</li>
 <li>bbbbbbbbb</li>
 <li class="last">ccccccccc</li>
</ul>
```

Now what I need for it is to jump to the list options when I type the first letter. So if I fx type "b" when the list is active, it will jump to the list "bbbbbbb" (and add a class, highlight or something other..)

But how do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

use this [CSS](http://pastebin.com/ZsajmRFp)

try this code using pure javascript

[autoComplete](http://pastebin.com/ikEudL52)

[How to Use it](http://pastebin.com/QHQcKN4s)

Comment: Hi mihir.. I would prefer "doing it myself" in an easier way rather than using +1000 lines of script to be honest if it's possible :S

Comment: Then read 9th and 10th Chapter from the book Professional JavaScript By Nicholas Zakas and u will get your solution.